# Disputed deletion on a Low Quality Review

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13747104) appears perfectly valid to me. It described in detail a valid response to the question. There were two linked examples but they're unaffiliated, so it wasn't likely to be an ad. And the answer was still valid if you removed the links. There were definitely spelling/grammar issues, but nothing I couldn't fix in two minutes with an *Edit*. Or so I thought.

Am I missing something? Is there something in particular that condemns this answer? Or was it just a difference of opinion on what could be salvaged?

[image]

Comment: It is deleted by a mod and the user is nuked so I expect it to be a spam case but it wasn't deleted by normal users casting spam flags. I can't find anything else on either that post or the url's as being used in spam before

Comment: We can haz screenshot of the answer?

Comment: Sure - http://i.stack.imgur.com/zhVU0.png

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It was spam for a commercial product, part of four nearly identical answers given by the same person to completely unrelated old posts:

- [.mp3 format piracy protection for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446033/mp3-format-piracy-protection-for-php/39550800#39550800)
- [Hide text inside audio file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267608/hide-text-inside-audio-file-with-php/39550837#39550837)
- [Watermarking sound, reading through iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359161/watermarking-sound-reading-through-iphone/39544574#39544574)
- [How to protect media content (video, audio) on Android from being saved/redistributed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625205/how-to-protect-media-content-video-audio-on-android-from-being-saved-redistri/39550964#39550964)

Look at the copyright footer on the bottom of the second linked page. Both of these pages were for the same commercial products, by the same person, with one acting as a shell for the other. This is a common spam tactic. Before the account was destroyed for spam, it was clear that the person behind it was the author of these tools.

Be very suspicious of brand new users posting answers to old questions that recommend commercial products, even if they surround the recommendation with what looks like a decent explanation. Spammers have taken to plagiarizing or making up text to mask the spam links they're placing in answers.

Comment: Good response but I believe it is **[shill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shill)**, not shell.

Comment: @Jeeped - I was using "as a shell" in the context of it being a shell company, which is commonly seen in these spam operations.

Comment: Ah, yes... now I see the context.

Comment: I guess, this is exactly the reason why such questions are closed as off-topic on SO, question asking for software may attract spam, though this specific question dodges that close reason by being too broad at the same time, i.e. not 100% asking for software…

Comment: I also [found](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Digital+audio+watermarking+allows+to+imperceptibly+embed%22) one [on security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/137056).

Comment: ...and [another one on SU](http://superuser.com/a/1125333).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen thanks for the flag and context(ie pointer to this question). Have killed the post on [su]

Comment: Is this something I should have picked up on in just the review queue? Now that I think about it I don't think I could have known this for sure without exiting the queue for a background check.

Comment: @4444 - Posts by new users on old questions that advocate for commercial solutions (with links) are almost always spam. When you see one of these in review, be extra cautious and check the account's profile if you have doubts. In this case, that would have revealed that the account had been destroyed and that this was an audit, but if you had caught them before that you would have seen the other posts. We rely on reviewers to be the first line in finding this spam, so we do want people to look into this when they see these signs.